# Add a PRIMARY KEY that auto increments starting with 1001

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is the code I used:

```
ALTER TABLE `event_all_copy` 
ADD `id` INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001 PRIMARY KEY;
```

I get the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO INCREMENT = 1001 PRIMARY KEY' at line 1

The code will run fine if I leave off the `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001`. If I add `id` then alter it:

```
ALTER TABLE event_all_copy AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;
```

it doesn't change the existing values.

Comment: If the value of the id has any meaning beyond the scope of the database, don't use auto-increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter the table telling it to start from `1000`:

```
ALTER TABLE `event_all_copy` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

So your query will be:

```
ALTER TABLE `event_all_copy` ADD `id` INT(5) PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `event_all_copy` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

You cannot have `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in the `ADD` query. The two queries should be two separate ones. To change the existing values, that's easy. You can do:

```
UPDATE `event_all_copy` SET `id` = `id` + 1000;
```

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` updated value will be set only for the newly entered records.

Comment: If I don't AUTO_INCREMENT in the ADD query I get an error because all values are 0 or NULL (duplicates, in any case). Your UPDATE code worked great!! Hadn't thought of that. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this after defining the table structure:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```